# BackgroundService Await Task.Delay in infinite loop leaks SqlConnection objects hard

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, sqlclient, .net-7.0

I have code similar to this running in multiple `BackgroundServices` **(.NET 7)**. After just a few days of runtime *(obviously, delay is in minutes (to hours) between loops)* leads to a massive Memory Leak in tens of thousands of dangling `SqlConnection` handles *(probably all of them ever used are still referenced, even if properly disconnected from the DB)*. I'm using .NET's SqlClient 5.0.1.

### MRE

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Memleak;

static class Program
{
    const string connectionString = "Server=lpc:localhost;"
        + "Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;"
        + "MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Pooling=False;";

    static async Task Main(params string[] args)
    {
        using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
        // not to forget it running
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

        using Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        long loop = 1;

        while (true)
        {
            await ConnectionAsync(ct);

            // this seems to be the issue (delay duration is irrelevant)
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), ct);

            process.Refresh();
            long workingSet = process.WorkingSet64;
            Console.WriteLine("PID:{0} RUN:{1:N0} RAM:{2:N0}",
                process.Id, loop, workingSet);

            ++loop;
        }
    }

    private static async Task ConnectionAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        using SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync(ct);

        using SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select cast(1 as bit);";

        using SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct);
        if (await reader.ReadAsync(ct))
        {
            _ = reader.GetBoolean(0);
        }
    }
}
```

### Leak

These following command prompt commands show the leak:

```cs
// dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
dotnet-dump collect -p pid
dotnet-dump analyze dump_name.dmp
dumpheap -type Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -stat
dumpheap -mt mtid
dumpobj objid
gcroot objid
```

Last command shows a huge list of `System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode` for a `SqlConnection` object.

### Question

Is this a bug or working as expected *(and if so, why)*? And is there any easy workaround except getting rid of all `async` code and just using `Threads`? I cannot use `Timers` since Delays are variable upon certain factors *(when work is available, delays are shorter; when work is not, delays are longer)*.

##### A non-async version does not leak

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace NotMemleak;

static class Program
{
    const string connectionString = "Server=lpc:localhost;" +
        "Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;" +
        "MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Pooling=False;";

    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
        // not to forget it running
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

        using Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        long loop = 1;
        while (loop < 1000)
        {
            Connection();

            // this seems to be the issue (delay duration is irrelevant)
            ct.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
            // Thread.Sleep();

            process.Refresh();
            long workingSet = process.WorkingSet64;
            Console.WriteLine("PID:{0} RUN:{1:N0} RAM:{2:N0}"
                , process.Id, loop, workingSet);

            ++loop;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("(press any key to exit)");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static void Connection()
    {
        using SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        using SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select cast(1 as bit);";

        using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            _ = reader.GetBoolean(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this due to an infinite while loop? have you tried running in limited times like 100 than 10000 and ....

Comment: Just ran it 999 times and added a `Console.ReadKey(true);` at the end. 999 `SqlConnection` dangling handles... so it's not the number of loops. The number of loops just reveals the leak since memory really starts to grow after a few days. It's the `await Task.DelayAsync` somehow.

Comment: And if you replace `Task.Delay` with `Thread.Sleep`? Hard to imagine how this delay could leak `SqlConnection` in unrelated code path.

Comment: @Evk Just rewrote the code without any `await` *(Thread)* and it doesn't leak. That's why I was so shocked. You have to run it to believe it. Unless there's something I don't understand in all this.

Comment: why are not using the same connection instead of creating/disposing of connection infinitely and that too very fast @CodeAngry

Comment: @viveknuna My code is way more complicated than this. This is a functional example. And it doesn't matter. Pooling (which I have enabled but disabled here) handles Connection reuse. Issue here is memory, not any kind of more efficient connection use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is related to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1810) in GitHub. As I understand it, it's a regression introduced in SqlClient 5.0.1. Basically, on this line:

```
await reader.ReadAsync(ct)
```

You pass a token, and the reader will internally register a callback function when this token is cancelled. However, this registration is not properly unregistered on all code paths. This in turn results in your `SqlConnection` instances being reachable from `CancellationTokenSource` through that callback registration (which references data reader, which references command, which references connection).

This is fixed in 5.1.0, which had a [stable release on 2023-01-19](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#stable-release-510---2023-01-19).